# SingleOrDefault : Not return null on Custome structure

Tags: c#, linq

I have structure,

```
public struct Test
{
    public int int1;
    public string str;
}
```

and in my code I have,

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>()
{ 
    new Test(){ int1 =1, str="abc" }, 
    new Test(){ int1 =2, str="abc" }
};
```

When I am trying to use SingleOrDefault on `List<Test> list` with search criteria int1 value equals 3

```
Test result = list.SingleOrDefault(o => o.int1 == 3);
```

Here result have value with default values, means int1 = 0 and str = null. Here I want `null` value if search criteria not satisfied. Anyone point me How I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get null returned because `Test` is a struct, a value type. Change `Test` to a class and it will return null.

Answer (score 5):

Value types are not nullable, so you either have to use a class, or a nullable `Test?`.

But if you want to stick with a `struct`, you should create a static field called `Empty` to check for empty values:

```
public struct Test
{
    public static readonly Test Emtpy = new Test();
    public int int1;
    public string str;

    public static bool operator ==(Test a, Test b)
    {
        return a.int1 == b.int1 && Equals(a.str, b.str);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Test a, Test b)
    {
        return !(a==b);
    }
}
```

It's a convention that you will find across the .Net framework. If you later want to check for `null` (what you probably do), check for `Test.Empty` instead.

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>(){ new Test(){ int1 =1,str="abc"}, new Test(){ int1 =2,str="abc"}};
Test result = list.SingleOrDefault(o => o.int1 == 3);

if (result != Test.Emtpy)
    ...
```

Comment: This assumes that Test.Empty is a semantically invalid value. I perceive this kind of trick as dirty. This is overloading the fields to hold multiple meanings.

Comment: @usr I don't see anything *tricky* or *dirty* about it. It's a common  pattern across the entire .Net framework. Or didn't you ever use `Guid.Empty`, `Point.Empty`, `Size.Empty`, `EventToken.Empty`...

Comment: did you ever use `Customer.Empty`, `User.Empty` or `Button.Empty`? It is a different thing for primitive values where the empty value makes sense. It is not just a placeholder. Guid.Empty is all-zeros. Size.Empty is then null-size and so on.; If the same is the case for the OP I'm all for it.

Answer (score 4):

A dirty fix:

```
    Test result = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.int1 == 3);

    if (result.Equals(default(Test)))
    {
        // not found
    }
    else
    {
        // normal work
    }
```

Use this only if you pretty sure that your original list never contains the default struct ( new Test() { int1 = 0, str = null } )

Comment: I am storing types of KeyValuePair in a list, so I don't have the option of modifying the code.  This is fine by me and not dirty at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Test? result = list.Select(o => (?Test)o).SingleOrDefault(o => o.Value.int1 == 3);
```

It is not pretty, but it does its job. You might want to extract that pattern into a helper method.

Comment: You could probably change the `Select` to a `Cast`

Comment: @Servy that would probably work but Cast runs on `IEnumerable` (not generic) so it introduces lots of boxing.